# Refresh the content of a page in stacklayout

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5

I've a stacklayout in a qt5-python program with 3 pages.
I change the page by clicking on three icons and it works perfectly.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QAction,
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QStackedLayout,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    QStatusBar,
    QToolBar,
)



### TESTING CLASS ###
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
class Color(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(palette)
### TESTING CLASS ###


I_INDEX_PAGE_DISC = 0
I_INDEX_PAGE_SONG = 1
I_INDEX_PAGE_INSTRUMENT = 2

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Studio Diary")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("img/icon/icone_main_window.png"))        
        
        ### IMPOSTA DIMENSIONE INTERFACCIA ###
        self.resize(900, 300)
        
        
        ### CREA LA BARRA DEGLI STRUMENTI ###
        tbMainToolBar = QToolBar("Studio Diary Toolbar")
        tbMainToolBar.setIconSize(QSize(64, 64))
        tbMainToolBar.setMovable(False)
        self.addToolBar(tbMainToolBar)
        
        
        lstButtonIcon = []
        
        ### CREA ICONA DISCO ###
        icoDisc = QIcon()
        icoDisc.addPixmap(QPixmap("img/icon/toolbar/icon_disc_on.png"))
        icoDisc.addPixmap(QPixmap("img/icon/toolbar/icon_disc_sel.png"), QIcon.Disabled)
        ### CREA BOTTONE DISCO ###
        bticDisc = QAction(icoDisc, "Dischi", self)
        bticDisc.setStatusTip("Gestisci i dischi")
        
        lstButtonIcon.append(bticDisc)
        
        ### CREA ICONA CANZONE ###
        icoSong= QIcon()
        icoSong.addPixmap(QPixmap("img/icon/toolbar/icon_song_on.png"))
        icoSong.addPixmap(QPixmap("img/icon/toolbar/icon_song_sel.png"), QIcon.Disabled)
        ### CREA BOTTONE DISCO ###
        bticSong = QAction(icoSong, "Canzoni", self)
        bticSong.setStatusTip("Gestisci le canzoni")
        
        lstButtonIcon.append(bticSong)
        
        ### CREA ICONA STRUMENTO ###
        icoInstrument = QIcon()
        icoInstrument.addPixmap(QPixmap("img/icon/toolbar/icon_instrument_on.png"))
        icoInstrument.addPixmap(QPixmap("img/icon/toolbar/icon_instrument_sel.png"), QIcon.Disabled)
        ### CREA BOTTONE STRUMENTO ###
        bticInstrument = QAction(icoInstrument, "Strumenti", self)
        bticInstrument.setStatusTip("Gestisci gli strumenthi")
        
        lstButtonIcon.append(bticInstrument)

        ### AGGIUNGI BOTTONE DISCO ###
        bticDisc.triggered.connect(lambda lam_pageDisc: self.activateDiscPage(lstButtonIcon))
        tbMainToolBar.addAction(bticDisc)
        ### AGGIUNGI BOTTONE CANZONE ###
        bticSong.triggered.connect(lambda lam_pageSong: self.activateSongPage(lstButtonIcon))
        tbMainToolBar.addAction(bticSong)
        ### AGGIUNGI BOTTONE CANZONE ###
        bticInstrument.triggered.connect(lambda lam_pageInstrument: self.activateInstrumentPage(lstButtonIcon))
        tbMainToolBar.addAction(bticInstrument)

        
        ### CREA IL LAYOUT GENERALE ###
        bvloMainPageLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.stacklayout = QStackedLayout()

        bvloMainPageLayout.addLayout(self.stacklayout)

        self.stacklayout.addWidget(Color("red"))
        self.stacklayout.addWidget(Color("green"))
        self.stacklayout.addWidget(Color("yellow"))

        wgtBodyApp = QWidget()
        wgtBodyApp.setLayout(bvloMainPageLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(wgtBodyApp)
        self.setStatusBar(QStatusBar(self))
        
 
    def buildDiscPage(self, strColor="red"):
        
        bhloDiscPage = QVBoxLayout()
        tvAlbumSong = TreeView()
        bhloDiscPage.addWidget(tvAlbumSong)
        bhloDiscPage.addWidget(QLabel("Song"))
        
    def buildSongPage(self):
        
        bhloSongPage = QHBoxLayout()
        self.stacklayout.addWidget(QLabel("cyan"))
      
        
    def buildInstrumentPage(self):
        
        bhloSongPage = QHBoxLayout()
        self.stacklayout.addWidget(QLabel("yellow"))       
        

  
    def activateDiscPage(self,mLstButtonIcon):
        
        ### IMPEDISCI CHE LA PAGINA VENGA RICHIAMATA SE E' GIA' STATA SELEZIONATA ###
        bticCurrentButton = mLstButtonIcon[I_INDEX_PAGE_DISC]
        blnIsEnabled = bticCurrentButton.isEnabled()
        if blnIsEnabled == True:
            self.buildDiscPage("green")
            self.stacklayout.setCurrentIndex(I_INDEX_PAGE_DISC)
            bticCurrentButton.setDisabled(True)
            self.resetIconButtonActivationStatus(mLstButtonIcon,I_INDEX_PAGE_DISC)
        
            
    def activateSongPage(self,mLstButtonIcon):
        
        ### IMPEDISCI CHE LA PAGINA VENGA RICHIAMATA SE E' GIA' STATA SELEZIONATA ###
        bticCurrentButton = mLstButtonIcon[I_INDEX_PAGE_SONG]
        blnIsEnabled = bticCurrentButton.isEnabled()
        if blnIsEnabled == True:
            self.buildSongPage()
            self.stacklayout.setCurrentIndex(I_INDEX_PAGE_SONG)
            bticCurrentButton.setDisabled(True)
            self.resetIconButtonActivationStatus(mLstButtonIcon,I_INDEX_PAGE_SONG)


    def activateInstrumentPage(self,mLstButtonIcon):
        
        ### IMPEDISCI CHE LA PAGINA VENGA RICHIAMATA SE E' GIA' STATA SELEZIONATA ###
        bticCurrentButton = mLstButtonIcon[I_INDEX_PAGE_INSTRUMENT]
        blnIsEnabled = bticCurrentButton.isEnabled()
        if blnIsEnabled == True:
            self.buildInstrumentPage()
            self.stacklayout.setCurrentIndex(I_INDEX_PAGE_INSTRUMENT)
            mLstButtonIcon[I_INDEX_PAGE_INSTRUMENT].setDisabled(True)
            self.resetIconButtonActivationStatus(mLstButtonIcon,I_INDEX_PAGE_INSTRUMENT)
        
        
    ### RESETTA LO STATUS DI ATTIVAZIONE DEI BOTTONI
    # === riattiva tutti i bottoni tranne quello corrente ===
    def resetIconButtonActivationStatus(self,mLstButtonIcon,mIntCurrent):
        
        for iButton in range (len(mLstButtonIcon)):
            
            btIcSingleButton = mLstButtonIcon [iButton]
            
            if  iButton != mIntCurrent:
                btIcSingleButton.setEnabled(True)


appMain = QApplication(sys.argv)

winMain = MainWindow()
winMain.show()

appMain.exec_()
```

When I click on the icon I will open the relative page, using the method activatePage() that recall buildPage()

I would that the page content will be update.

For example: In a page I will query the database or in another one I will pass some parameters to the buildPage() function to change some elements or style in the page.

How should I modify these functions?

[edit]

0

This code works perfectly but I would like to know another thing about it.

I've a layout like the one in the screenshoot.

The treeview is created by a class that builds the tree by querying a database.

I would like to update it when I add a new album. Can I update only the treeview and not all the page (maybe separating in two layouts)? I need to do it in other page of the application so I would learn how to do it.

Everytime I click on the icon/button on the toolbar should I query the database to update the view? In other pages I could add some infos.

(see the image in the answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QStackedLayout works with "pages" which are *reusable*, just like a "tabbed" interface does (in fact, QTabWidget uses a private QStackedWidget, which is based on QStackedLayout).

Considering the fact that pages are reusable, your issue is that you're not actually switching to the pages, but you're continuously adding a *new* page every time.

While dynamic creation of pages is obviously possible, even for optimization purposes, in your case you don't need that since you only have 3 pages.

Since those 3 pages will probably have their own "static" layout, a better solution is to create separate subclasses for each page, which allows creating specific function to update the data whenever required. This is a far better approach than creating single functions that do almost the same thing when creating/switching pages, and you can have a single interface to access/set the data from and to each page.

This is a possible implementation:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Disco(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.artista = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.titolo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow('Artista', self.artista)
        layout.addRow('Titolo', self.titolo)

    def setData(self, data):
        self.artista.setText(data.get('artista', ''))
        self.titolo.setText(data.get('titolo', ''))

    def getData(self):
        return {'artista': self.artista.text(), 'titolo': self.titolo.text()}


class Canzoni(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 2)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(('Titolo', 'Durata'))
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Aggiungi')
        layout.addWidget(self.addButton)
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(lambda: 
            self.table.insertRow(self.table.rowCount()))

    def setData(self, data):
        self.table.clearContents()
        canzoni = data.get('canzoni', [])
        self.table.setRowCount(len(canzoni))
        for row, (titolo, durata) in enumerate(canzoni):
            self.table.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(titolo))
            durataItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            durataItem.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, int(durata))
            self.table.setItem(row, 1, durataItem)

    def getData(self):
        canzoni = []
        for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            canzoni.append([
                self.table.item(row, 0).text(), 
                self.table.item(row, 1).data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole), 
            ])
        return {'canzoni': canzoni}


class Strumenti(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(('Artista', 'Strumenti'))
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Aggiungi')
        layout.addWidget(self.addButton)
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(lambda: 
            self.table.insertRow(self.table.rowCount()))

    def setData(self, data):
        self.table.clearContents()
        strumenti = data.get('strumenti', [])
        self.table.setRowCount(len(strumenti))
        for row, (artista, strumento) in enumerate(strumenti):
            self.table.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(artista))
            self.table.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(strumento))

    def getData(self):
        strumenti = []
        for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            strumenti.append([
                self.table.item(row, 0).text(), 
                self.table.item(row, 1).text(), 
            ])
        return {'strumenti': strumenti}


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.stackWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stackWidget)

        self.disco = Disco()
        self.stackWidget.addWidget(self.disco)

        self.canzoni = Canzoni()
        self.stackWidget.addWidget(self.canzoni)

        self.strumenti = Strumenti()
        self.stackWidget.addWidget(self.strumenti)

        self.pages = self.disco, self.canzoni, self.strumenti

        self.loadAction = self.menuBar().addAction('Load')
        self.loadAction.triggered.connect(self.loadData)
        self.saveAction = self.menuBar().addAction('Save')
        self.saveAction.triggered.connect(self.saveData)

        for i, actionName in enumerate(('Disco', 'Canzoni', 'Strumenti')):
            action = self.menuBar().addAction(actionName)
            action.setData(i)

        self.menuBar().triggered.connect(self.switchPageAction)

        self.setStyleSheet('''
            Disco {
                background: red;
            }
            Canzoni {
                background: green;
            }
            Strumenti {
                background: yellow;
            }
        ''')
        self.switchPage(0)

    def loadData(self):
        data = {
            'artista': 'Elio e le Storie Tese', 
            'titolo': 'Elio Samaga Hukapan Kariyana Turu', 
            'canzoni': [
                ['John Holmes', 206], 
                ['Nubi di ieri sul nostro domani odierno', 253], 
            ], 
            'strumenti': [
                ['Elio', 'Voci'], 
                ['Rocco', 'Tastiere'], 
            ]
        }
        for page in self.pages:
            page.setData(data)

    def saveData(self):
        data = {}
        for page in self.pages:
            data.update(page.getData())
        print(data)

    def switchPageAction(self, action):
        index = action.data()
        if index is not None:
            self.switchPage(index)

    def switchPage(self, index):
        self.stackWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        for action in self.menuBar().actions():
            action.setEnabled(action.data() != index)
```

<sup>Note that newly created rows in QTableWidget always return `None` for `item()` if no value has been set yet, so the `saveFunction()` above may throw exceptions, I obviously didn't add all required checkings; it's up to you to add proper data type checking.</sup>
<sup>Also consider that setting the palette on a parent widget propagates the palette to *all* its children too, including subchildren, that's why I used stylesheets instead, which allows using a proper *selector* for the class that requires specific properties; also note that I chose to use QFrame to simplify things, as QWidget doesn't directly support stylesheet drawing. Alternatively, you can use `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground)`.</sup>